# VS Code Can't select Python as Interpreter even though it is installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pythoninterpreter

I installed the latest version of VS Code an Python (3.11.3). I also manually entered the path to select python, but still doesnt work.

How can I set Python as Interpreter?

This is the output that I get:

> Experiment 'pythonPromptNewToolsExt' is active
> conda info --json
>
> > ~\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe -I ~.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py ~.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py
> > [ERROR 2023-3-13 8:56:5.480]: [Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
> > at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
> > at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
> > at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)] {
> > errno: -4058,
> > code: 'ENOENT',
> > syscall: 'spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;',
> > path: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;',
> > spawnargs: [
> > '-c',
> > 'C:\Users\cenne\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe -I c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py'
> > ],
> > cmd: 'C:\Users\cenne\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe -I c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py'
> > }
> > ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -I ~.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py ~.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py
> > [ERROR 2023-3-13 8:56:5.872]: [Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
> > at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
> > at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
> > at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)] {
> > errno: -4058,
> > code: 'ENOENT',
> > syscall: 'spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;',
> > path: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;',
> > spawnargs: [
> > '-c',
> > 'C:\Users\cenne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -I c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py'
> > ],
> > cmd: 'C:\Users\cenne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -I c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py'
> > }
> > ~\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe -I ~.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py ~.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py
> > [ERROR 2023-3-13 8:56:7.494]: [Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
> > at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
> > at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
> > at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)] {
> > errno: -4058,
> > code: 'ENOENT',
> > syscall: 'spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;',
> > path: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;',
> > spawnargs: [
> > '-c',
> > 'C:\Users\cenne\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe -I c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py'
> > ],
> > cmd: 'C:\Users\cenne\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11.exe -I c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py'
> > }
> > ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -I ~.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py ~.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py
> > [ERROR 2023-3-13 8:56:7.879]: [Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
> > at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
> > at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
> > at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)] {
> > errno: -4058,
> > code: 'ENOENT',
> > syscall: 'spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;',
> > path: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;',
> > spawnargs: [
> > '-c',
> > 'C:\Users\cenne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -I c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py'
> > ],
> > cmd: 'C:\Users\cenne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -I c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\get_output_via_markers.py c:\Users\cenne\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.0\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py'
> > }
> > Starting Pylance language server.

I also manually entered the path to select python, but still doesnt work.

I added the path to python in the system environment variables.

Comment: Install the [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), install the [python interpreter](https://www.python.org/downloads/). This [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) may be helpful.

Comment: If you run 'python --version' command in cmd, will you get the information?

Comment: Yes, I get the information that python version 3.11.3 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT at
> ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)

Check your environment variables:

Mycomputer>properties>Advance System Settings>Environment Variables>System Variables

add the following path:

[image]

```
ComSpec C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. The path you suggested is already added in the system variables.

Comment: @flexyflash Have you tried to use other version of Python extension in vscode extension store.